# why cant I declare a string in a flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

[image: ...]

I want to declare a string which has a value of a color in a random widget...
why it is not woorking?

Comment: Because flutter works on data types you can't give like that to a widget if you want to give decalre a color variable then pass that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It don't work like this, the `backgroundColor` is a property of `FloatingActionButton` so you can't just put the properties and it's value in a String,

Rather you need to store the value in the variable and give it to the Widget's property,

Here in your case we'll store `Colors.green` in the 'Color' typed variable and give it to the `backgroundColor` property:

```
Color bgColor = Colors.green;
```

and will be used as:

```
FloatingActionButton(
   backgroundColor: bgColor,
   onPressed: (){},
   child: Text('Button')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

FloatingActionButton takes a named parameter.

The problem isnt directly the declared variable but the way you try to pass the argument.

If you use e.g a Text widget it would be working.

```
Text(
  gColor
)
```

If you plan to pass a color you need to specify a color type and use it in the TextStyle of the TextWidget. Take an suitable type:

```
Text(String data, {Key? key, TextStyle? style, StrutStyle? strutStyle, TextAlign? textAlign, TextDirection? textDirection, Locale? locale, bool? softWrap, TextOverflow? overflow, double? textScaleFactor, int? maxLines, String? semanticsLabel, TextWidthBasis? textWidthBasis, TextHeightBehavior? textHeightBehavior, Color? selectionColor})
```

See the docs for the action button
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html

```
FloatingActionButton({Key? key, Widget? child, String? tooltip, Color? foregroundColor, Color? backgroundColor, Color? focusColor, Color? hoverColor, Color? splashColor, Object? heroTag = const _DefaultHeroTag(), double? elevation, double? focusElevation, double? hoverElevation, double? highlightElevation, double? disabledElevation, required VoidCallback? onPressed, MouseCursor? mouseCursor, bool mini = false, ShapeBorder? shape, Clip clipBehavior = Clip.none, FocusNode? focusNode, bool autofocus = false, MaterialTapTargetSize? materialTapTargetSize, bool isExtended = false, bool? enableFeedback})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `child` of a `FloatingActionButton` is declared as:

```
final Widget? child;
```

This means it needs to be a Widget, not a String.  You need to put it in a `Text` widget, or find some other way to turn your String into a Widget.